# Comprehension question about the NavController in Android

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

I just started to use the Jetpack Navigation in Android and I have a question. I have the following method inside a Fragment that implements View.OnClickListener

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButton_Softdrinks_en) {

        int amount = 1;
        Menu_FragmentDirections.ActionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks action = Menu_FragmentDirections
                .actionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks(amount);

        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);



    }

}
```

Basically the method works but I do not really comprehend why. The View in the method declaration are supposed to be ImageButtons. When using the command:"Navigation.findNavController(view)" Android searches for the Navcontroller of the view. Given that the view is an ImageButtom I do not understand why the navigation works. The ImageButtoms do not have a NavController or a NavHost. Would anyone mind explaining this to me. I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `Navigation.findNavController(View)` on any `View` in the `View` hierarchy. The system will then traverse up the hierarchy until it finds the parent `Fragment` (the `NavHostFragment`), and then it will find the NavController of the `NavHostFragment`.

Comment: Thanks Gavin for your comment. But the view itself is an ImageBottom. Further I have not implemented the NavController  and even in the XML layout file of the container acticity I do not specify anything about the NavController. I just use the tag "app:defaultNavHost="true"" within a fragment. So I am still quite confused why the things work this way. How does Android know where to find the NavController and that the view in the method descprtion is not the view it should look for the NavController (because it is an ImageBottom without any Nav elemnt)

Comment: You don't implement the `NavController` yourself. You just specify a `NavHostFragment` and a `navGraph`, and Android takes care of swapping out `Fragments` as you navigate between them. The `ImageButton` is a child of a `Fragment`, and this `Fragment` is a destination in the `navGraph`. So it can find the `navController` from any `View` contained within any of the destination `Fragments`. It does this by simply traversing up the `View` hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Gavin for your comments and effort. So can I just always use the code "Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
" within any method and it will navigate to the correct place (indicated in the NavGraph)?

Comment: Yes, assuming you're inside a `ClickListener` which provides a `View`, or you have a `View` reference from some other means. You can also call `findNavController(this).navigate(action)`, which is a method of the `Fragment` class. They're basically the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and help Gavin. I accpeted your answer and upvoted it.